# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS won't boot (Mount /dev/sda2 problem?)

Tags: boot, mount, fsck

Today my laptop which runs Ubuntu 14.04LTS will no longer boot ever since I restarted it this morning. I was SSH'd onto a server at my college campus, and put the computer to sleep. When I woke it up my terminal was frozen so I manually shut it down and noticed that I had no wifi so I rebooted my computer. Ever since then the computer boots to the GRUB manager, and will freeze when I try to launch it through the splashscreen.
I have tried launching through the GRUB recovery mode and using fsck but I get this error:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
  Automatically removing dirty bit.
Performing changes.
/dev/sda1: 6 files, 864/130812 clusters
mountall: fsck /boot/efi [745] terminated with status 1
/dev/sda2: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
         (i.e., without -a or -p options)
mountall: fsck / [746] terminated with status 4
mountall: Filesystem has errors: /
```

I am very new to Linux/Ubuntu and this is the first time that I have ever encountered something like this. So I apologize if the title is a bit misleading, I tried to make it as informative as possible based on what I understand from the error.

If there is anyway at all that I can recover my computer, or even just the data that I had on the harddrive I would really appreciate someone helping. Thank you so much in advance!